# Configure in Apache two Ruby on Rails apps in the same Server with same IP

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

I previously ran an two Ruby and Rails applications, one of them by using **rails console** command, the another one using Apache trough Phusion Passenger. Both applications ran in same IP, the only difference was the application running wih rails console was accesible from port 3000.

Now, I would like to run both apps with Apache, but I know what exactly configure to do that. I read something VirtualHosts, but i don't get it. Considering that I only have one server and one domain, i just used a different port. I tried several times to something similar to this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    #ServerAdmin @dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot /webserver/myapp/public
    ServerName myapp-Development
    <Directory /webserver/myapp/public>
         AllowOverride all
         Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog logs/k2-error_log
    CustomLog logs/k2-access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:3000>
    #ServerAdmin @dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot /webserver/myapp2-admin/public
    ServerName myapp2-admin
    <Directory /webserver/myapp2-admin/public>
         AllowOverride all
         Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
    #ErrorLog logs/k2-error_log
    #CustomLog logs/k2-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Didn't work, i just have access to the first application by typing the IP in browser.

How can I have 2 RoR applications in same server available in different ports?

OR

OPTIONAL: How can I have myapp2 to run in same port 80, but available in this direction: some.ip.address/admin?

Using CentOS 5.7 in a Amazon EC2 instance.

I found an answer in this question, the problem is that I dont' have a domain to create CNAMES records for subdomains: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203580/creating-subdomains-in-amazon-ec2

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to edit, ports.conf, you need to add another Listen to make apache bind to that port as well.

Comment: And where is this file?

Comment: On centos apparently the directive resides in  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

Answer (score 1):

check my answer [here](https://serverfault.com/a/410351) to a similar question about serving multiple rails applications from sub-url's.

If you want to server your two rails apps from two different ports, apart from the virtual host, you have to also add to your apache conf

```
Listen 80
Listen 3000
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:3000
```